# Custom style scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroller

Does anyone here know any tutorial/guide lines/link that will help me create an scrollbar like the one at http://www.wdyl.com/#apple [on the left top]

Comment: jQuery ui slider can be styled relatively easily to do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [**jQuery.fracs**](http://larsjung.de/fracs/), which I read about just the other day on [daily.js](http://dailyjs.com/2011/08/09/jquery-roundup/).

It does not have the *magnifying effect* like the link in the question, however it does generate a dimensionally correct tiny version of the page it is on, which I think is really smart.

Comment: Thanks. Been looking for a while!!